# Create a native version update of an Android app written using Ionic Framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play, apk, signing

I am about to create version 2 of an application that was first written using `Ionic` framework.

I would like to verify one thing that concerns updating the original app on `Google Play Store`.

When I create a new project in `Android Studio` :

I should give the same package name as the original app
I should sign with the same keystore and passwords

Is there anything else I have to take into consideration?

Comment: That should be enough, but you may consider user's data migration

Comment: Good point! hopefully I think there has been no data saved locally but I will verify.

Comment: Is there a solution for data migration, in my case I have this problem that I shared here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549703/data-migration-after-updating-android-ionic-app-to-an-android-native-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Play Store Ionic to Native App Transition :**

1.On google play store publishing ionic app  are same process as publishing native app.

2.Develop build and deploy any cross platform app(ex:ionic,cordova) and later easily move to native app.

3.In Android Native App build gradle file , package name(application ID) should be same for different versions of app(in your case ionic). Also signing certificate(keystore) remain same during version change.