# Data Migration after updating Android Ionic App to an Android Native version

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework, android-room, data-migration

After I reached the limits of Ionic I boldly decided to detach from the web world and learn Kotlin to rewrite the app in the native language.

After an amusing challenge I have my new app up and running. But I forgot about one of the most important details : **Data Migration**.

The Ionic version stores data localy in an SQLite database: I am using this Ionic Native Plugin [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite) and I nearly do the same thing as this guy over [here](https://www.positronx.io/ionic-sqlite-database-crud-app-example-tutorial/) the only major diffrence I am on Capacitor.

In the new native version of my app I am using Room as an abstraction layer over SQLite.
Is there anyway to do this migration ? I don't want my users to lose data of course and my app is offline so there is no way to upload data to the cloud as a shortcut.

Also, can I deploy the new app now, and block update from the old version until I find a solution ? or it s not possible in the Play Store ?